# Displaying Current Wallet Balance from Tera Wallet on Elementor Page using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, elementor

I have implemented Tera Wallet on my WordPress website, and it displays the current balance in a specific text element on one page. Now, I want to retrieve the current balance text and display it in a specific text element on another page created with Elementor using HTML and JavaScript.

On the page where the wallet balance is displayed, the HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="woo-wallet-content">
    <div class="woo-wallet-content-heading">
        <h3 class="woo-wallet-content-h3">Balance</h3>
        <p class="woo-wallet-price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>500.00</bdi></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the other page created with Elementor, I have an HTML element (e.g., **`<span>`**) with a specific CSS class where I want to display the current wallet balance. The Elementor page structure looks like this:

```
<div class="elementor-text-class">Current Wallet Balance: <span id="balance-display"></span></div>
```

I would like to retrieve the current balance text (e.g., "$500.00") from the first page and dynamically display it in the **`<span>`** element with the ID **`balance-display`** on the second page.

Could someone please help me with the HTML and JavaScript code that can extract the wallet balance text from one page and display it on another page using Elementor, HTML, and JavaScript?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: To be able to do this in client-side JavaScript, you will first of all have to _load_ that other page, that the information is actually in - either in an iframe, or in the background via JavaScript. Or, you could make the originating page store the value into localStorage, and then have the second page read it from there (but that will of course only work, if the user _visits_ the originating page first.)

Comment: But how exactly did the value get into the first place to begin with? Something server-side must have determined it, I suppose, some sort of API call or whatever? Then it would probably make more sense to have it inserted into that second page also on the server-side already.

Comment: @CBroe I used a plugin called tera wallet, that basically a wallet where user can add and use that balance to purchase stuffs on my site. so the total balance is displayed on the my account>wallet sections, so I want to get the text from that balance and display it to another place or site

Comment: Trying to get this "from" another page, is a bad idea. If you did it client-side, then the user would have to visit that page, before the info was available on any other pages - and if the value gets _updated_, they would have to visit that account page _again_, to update the value stored in localStorage - until they do, that other page would show the _old_ value. And doing it server-side, would mean that you would need to make an HTTP request to your own site, while supplying the user's current session id, and parse the tiny info you are interested in, out of the whole source code.

Comment: The plugin has a REST API - https://github.com/malsubrata/woo-wallet/wiki/API-V3 - so that would really rather be the way to go. You could create your own shortcode that makes that API request, and returns whatever you want to insert into the page - and then you just put the shortcode somewhere into the content, and let WP parse it.

Comment: @CBroe . they gave a option to put that on header but since I am not use the default header, thats why i can't get that what i need.

Comment: @CBroe, see they gave a option to put it on header, but I am not using the default header
[link](https://ibb.co/RCNYJ7D)

Answer (score 0):

I used this shortcode "[mini-wallet]" for tera wallet to show the wallet balance.